# MATLAB JIT for-loop optimization

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization, iteration, jit

**Setup -** From the following test code, it seems like MATLAB JIT optimizes for-loop if number of iterations are more than six.
After 6th and 7th iteration, there is huge performance rise. The difference keeps oscillating after 7th iteration (from the output figure).

**Doubt -** I am not able to understand how and why MATLAB JIT optimizes after minimum number of iterations? Also can this minimum number be changed?

**Test code -**

```
clearvars
clc

tic
N = 30;
a = NaN(1,N);
b = NaN(1,N);

for i=1:1:N
a(i)= toc;
end

(a.*1000000)' % time stamps in microseconds
diff(a.*1000000)' % difference in successive time stamps in microseconds
plot(diff(a.*1000000)')
```

**Output -** (first 10 values are shown)

```
ans =

  154.1000
  196.4000
  223.2000
  249.1000
  553.6000
  760.9000
  762.9000
  763.3000
  763.6000
  764.0000


ans =

   42.3000
   26.8000
   25.9000
  304.5000
  207.3000
    2.0000
    0.4000
    0.3000
    0.4000
    0.3000
```

**Output figure -** Oscillations after 7th iteration:

[image: Oscillations after 7th iteration]

Comment: 1) I think you are measuring wrong, but I can not see this effect 2) JIT depends on the code, your results are not aplicable to all for loops. 3) you are reaching the limit of measurement, I get 0us for lots of iterations in my machine.

Comment: 4) If you are right, its likely that the answer is proprietary...

Comment: 1) It is strange that you are getting 0us. Unfortunately I have only one machine to test for now. 2) To circumvent the limits of measurement with tic/toc, I tried adding some dummy calculations within for loop and have the same output. 3) I have another test simulation code where nested for-loop shows optimization on the 2nd run (which is consistent with what MATLAB JIT does). 4) You're right, it must be proprietary, and MATLAB JIT documentation also does not elaborate this in details

Comment: yes, you are more or less right. I get differing results, but in general after the 5th or 6th iteration, the code is much faster. Likely a manual heuristic threshold for the JIT

Comment: Given that the loop iterations are pre-determined, it is unlikely that the JIT will "decide" to do something after a given number of iterations. Before the loop starts, it's known it will run 30 times. The JIT can decide before the first run whether it's sufficient iterations to actually compile or not. If you put your code inside a function, then the whole code will be compiled before the function starts, and each loop iteration should be equally fast. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] I presume that you ran this by copy-pasting to the command line. This is a bad way of timing things, the JIT doesn't do much in this case. Your timing differences might be related to loading the `toc` function, or to something weird that goes on inside it. Who knows?

Comment: My system has a more precise clock that yours, I see diffs between 0.3850 and 0.4190 when I run your code. If you run it twice in succession, you'll see that the second time the behaviour is totally different than the first, which indicates that this is related to warming up. In the second run, the first value is the largest, because it includes the creation of some arrays, the other values are all identical (within timing precision).

Comment: 1) I wrapped the code in a function the optimization starts from the 2nd iteration which is in-line with JIT behavior. 2) I was not running the test-code in command line, instead it was a section in a script file. And I was running that particular section only. (I guess this is the problem, JIT does not works reliably when running a section of code) 3) I ran the code in command line, and it is almost as fast and optimized as a function.

Comment: The timing of the first iteration includes the creation of the output matrices, as well as entering the loop (e.g. setting up the list of values to iterate over). It makes no sense to compare that time with the other iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Looks like the problem is how I'm executing the code**. In the questing the code is a section, which is a part of a script file. I am running the particular section only to execute the test code. This is where JIT is messing-up.

However, the following scenarios gives fast and consistent executing -

1. executing the code is a separate script file
2. executing the code in command line
3. executing the code by wrapping up in a function

The actual problem in the question is solved but there is an another quirk - If in the same scenario (in the section), if I use nested for-loops the optimization starts from the 2nd iteration onward. So this part of JIT optimization remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the loop iterations are pre-determined, it is unlikely that the JIT will "decide" to do something after a given number of iterations. Before the loop starts, it's known it will run 30 times. The JIT can decide before the first run whether it's sufficient iterations to actually compile or not. If you put your code inside a function (or apparently also a script file nowadays, this wasn't the case in older versions of MATLAB), then the whole code will be compiled before the function starts, and each loop iteration should be equally fast. Running a code section, or copy-pasting code to the command line, doesn't allow the JIT to do its thing.

Note also that your timing code is odd: the time measured in the first loop iteration includes the initialization code (creating `N`, `a` and `b`, as well as creating the array over which will be looped), and therefore will always be larger than the other iteration times.

Try this code instead, it times code run *inside* the loop:

```matlab
N = 30;
a = NaN(1,N);
for ii=1:N
   tic;
   for jj=1:1e4
      1;
   end
   a(ii) = toc;
end
a
```

One typical run shows this output:

```
a =

   1.0e-03 *

  Columns 1 through 11

    0.4317    0.4348    0.4375    0.4327    0.4250    0.4494    0.4355    0.4361    0.4198    0.4180    0.5554

  Columns 12 through 22

    0.6504    0.5350    0.8944    0.5387    0.4208    0.4554    0.4868    0.5484    0.4167    0.4143    0.5975

  Columns 23 through 30

    0.4196    0.4157    0.4157    0.4157    0.4158    0.4157    0.4163    0.4166
```

As you can see, the first loop iteration takes the same amount of time as all the other loop iterations. For some iterations the time goes up a bit, this is caused by other stuff happening on the computer at the same time. `tic`/`toc` does wall time, not process time. This shows why one should not use `tic`/`toc` to time code unless it runs for a long time. `timeit` is always a better choice: it runs the code multiple times, so it can discard the runs for which there were unrelated delays.

Comment: You are right about the use of tic/toc. I mistakenly included initialization of N,a and b after tic. The tic/toc is very jittery for small precise time measurements. Using diff(a) on your (as well as mine) code shows timing jitter. I appreciate your detailed answer. Please do check my answer also, where I found that the problem of high time lag in first 5 iterations is because I was using test code as a section in the man script, and using "run section" option in MATLAB for ececution of the code.